# sed repeating the last line in the stream

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, quoting

I have code in a script similar to this...

```
smbconffile="/etc/samba/smb.conf"
sed -i 's/.*[\[CMI\]]/\[CMI\$\]/' $smbconffile && echo "Success" || "Failed"
sed -i 's/.*[\[LOCAL\]]/\[LOCAL\$\]/' $smbconffile && echo "Success" || "Failed"
sed -i 's/.*[\[NATIONAL\]]/\[NATIONAL\$\]/' $smbconffile && echo "Success" || "Failed"
```

this changes the names of the shares in the samba conf (smb.conf) to the CMI$, LOCAL$, NATIONAL$.

the problem i am having is that after the second sed command, sed finds "NATIONAL" but it renames it as "LOCAL$" instead of "NATIONAL$". Does anyone see an issue with the commands? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing character classes (a list of characters inside square brackets) with the smb.conf share names which are surrounded by square bracket literals. Also, the `echo` command is not well-formed: in the case where `sed` exits with a non-zero status, the shell will attempt to invoke the command `Failed`.

A few suggestions:

1. Remove the character class (outer brackets)
2. Remove the leading `.*` which will remove leading comments, etc.
3. Run a single `sed` command with multiple statements
4. Fix the error case message

```
sed -i 's/\[CMI\]/\[CMI\$\]/;
        s/\[LOCAL\]/\[LOCAL\$\]/;
        s/\[NATIONAL\]/\[NATIONAL\$\]/' $smbconffile && echo "Success" || echo "Failed"`
```

You could use backreferences to avoid retyping the original prefix in the replacement expression (e.g., `[CMI'), but that can make the expressions even harder to read.

Another suggest is to use Perl which has readable grouping and backreferences IMO:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(\[(?:CMI|LOCAL|NATIONAL))\]/$1\$]/g' $smbconffile \
    && echo "Success" || echo "Failed"
```

**Edit:** To clarify, the problem with the original expression with the outer brackets is that you are creating a character class which matches any string containing (in the first case) `[`, `C`, `M`, `I`, `]` in any order followed by a `]`. For example:

```
$ echo '[IMC]' | sed 's/[\[CMI\]]/[something_else]/'
[IM[something_else]

$ echo '[FOOM]' | sed 's/[\[CMI\]]/[something_else]/'
[FOO[something_else]
```

Removing the outer brackets removes the character class so the expression will match the exact substring provided.

Comment: great answer! Your answer fix it! Explained very well with the addition edit. If only I had enough reputation points to reward your answer.

Comment: Aditionally `sed` has no exit code if it is not stated by *q* or *Q* sed's actions so the constructions like `sed && command || command` is void. Instead you can use *t* or *T* operations to produce indicator messages.

Comment: @Costas: I observed that `sed` will exit nonzero on fatal errors such as a missing input file, but did not know about the `q` or `Q` actions. Thank you for clarifying.